# Save a dictionary for later reading in android java

Tags: java, android, dictionary

This is my first android app and first time using java so please be patient with me.

In my app in the `MainActivity.java` i fetch data from a server and form it into a dictionary which i call `listings`. I need to access listings in my next activity `webResults.java`, I would preferably want to save it to Local Storage so the user cannot read it, and i can access it a few different times. I've tried using the `FileOutputStream` doing the following:

```
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

But that is only a string and not a dictionary.

How can I save a dictionary for later retrieval in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best data storage option for Android Apps is the [SQLite-Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) build in to Android. It is private to the App, so every app has it own database and the User can not access the database in the file structure.

Please read the linked google tutorial on how to read from and write to theSQLite Database. There are two demo projects linked below the article with example code on how to read and write.